# Producer Consumer Never terminating

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, mutex, producer-consumer

I am using multi thread and I have made a program where producer creates values and insert into buffer and consumer consumes it.
However consumer never terminates. I would like to terminate the consumer process when there is nothing left to consume.

Is there any way to change the code?

This is the main code

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Producer/consumer program illustrating conditional variables */

/* Size of shared buffer */
#define BUF_SIZE 3

int buffer[BUF_SIZE];                           /* shared buffer */
int add=0;                                      /* place to add next element */
int rem=0;                                      /* place to remove next element */
int num=0;                                      /* number elements in buffer */
pthread_mutex_t m=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;    /* mutex lock for buffer */
pthread_cond_t c_cons=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; /* consumer waits on this cond var */
pthread_cond_t c_prod=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; /* producer waits on this cond var */

void *producer(void *param);
void *consumer(void *param);

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;       /* thread identifiers */
    int i;

    /* create the threads; may be any number, in general */
    if (pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,producer,NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to create producer thread\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    if (pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,consumer,NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to create consumer thread\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    /* wait for created thread to exit */
    pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
    printf ("Parent quiting\n");
}
```

This is the producer part

```
/* Produce value(s) */
void *producer(void *param)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=20; i++) {
        /* Insert into buffer */
        pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
        if (num > BUF_SIZE) exit(1);    /* overflow */
        while (num == BUF_SIZE)         /* block if buffer is full */
            pthread_cond_wait (&c_prod, &m);
        /* if executing here, buffer not full so add element */
        buffer[add] = i;
        add = (add+1) % BUF_SIZE;
        num++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&m);
        pthread_cond_signal (&c_cons);
        printf ("producer: inserted %d\n", i);  fflush (stdout);
    }
    printf ("producer quiting\n");  fflush (stdout);
}
```

This is the consumer part

```
/* Consume value(s); Note the consumer never terminates */
void *consumer(void *param)
{
    int i;
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
        if (num < 0) exit(1);   /* underflow */
        while (num == 0)        /* block if buffer empty */
            pthread_cond_wait (&c_cons, &m);
        /* if executing here, buffer not empty so remove element */
        i = buffer[rem];
        rem = (rem+1) % BUF_SIZE;
        num--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&m);
        pthread_cond_signal (&c_prod);
        printf ("Consume value %d\n", i);  fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: How should the consumer know that it should terminate?

Comment: @user253751 How do I tell the consumer to terminate if there is no more buffer to consume??

Comment: You don't want it to terminate when there's no more buffer to consume. If it terminates when there's no more buffer to consume, then the producer produces 1 item, the consumer consumes 1 item, the consumer terminates, and the producer produces 19 more items that never ever get consumed because the consumer already terminated.

Comment: So what do I do to return to main function after consuming all 20 numbers produced by the producer?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is for the producer to put something in the buffer that tells the consumer it's quitting. Since your numbers go from 1 to 20, you could choose that a 0 or a -1 means the end. When the producer ends it puts -1 in the buffer and when the consumer sees a -1 in the buffer it also ends.